# How to suppress 'Maybe this is program method' warnings from ProGuard

Tags: proguard

I'm using ProGuard with my Android application and I'm running getting the warnings below in my build log. I've added the appropriate '-keep public class com.foo.OtherClass { public static *; }' statement to my proguard.cfg file, but I still get the warnings. My app runs fine and is dynamically accessing the class correctly. Is it possible to suppress these warnings?

```
[proguard] Note: com.foo.MyClass accesses a method 'getInstance()' dynamically
[proguard]       Maybe this is program method 'com.foo.OtherClass { com.foo.OtherClass getInstance(); }'
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can avoid it by explicitly mentioning the method in the configuration:

```
-keep class com.foo.OtherClass { com.foo.OtherClass getInstance(); }
```

Alternatively, you can suppress notes on a class:

```
-dontnote com.foo.MyClass
```

Answer (score 6):

You suppress all messages of type Note by adding the following line:

```
-dontnote **
```

Comment: Even this doesnt help me

Comment: Don't forget the `**`. That initially tripped me up.